# Replacing parentheses using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, replace

I am trying to replace the parenthesis around a number or single letter (1), (a) with 1. and 2. I want to leave the longer words in place (reprehenderit)

This is what I have tried. The full stop appears on both sides of all former parentheses when I only want it to appear once.

Thank you

```py
import re

text = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\n\n(1)consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt\n\n(2)ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip\n\n(a) ex ea (commodo consequat). Duis aute irure dolor in (reprehenderit) in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu\n\n(b) fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'''

result = re.sub(r'[\(\)]','.\1', text)

Print(result)
```

What I am getting:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

.1. consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt

.2. ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip

.a. ex ea .commodo consequat.. Duis aute irure dolor in .reprehenderit. in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu

.b. fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

I am looking for:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

1. consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
2. ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
    a. ex ea (commodo consequat). Duis aute irure dolor in (reprehenderit) in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
    b. fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Comment: Those dots are not the only problem as `"\1"` is  a char with octal code `\001`. You need something like `re.sub(r'\(([\da-z]+)\)', r'\1. ', s)`

Comment: of course. regex can be a pain to get right. I have tried this and it works. thank you for your help. much appreciated.

Comment: You have no capture groups in your regexp, what are you expecting `\1` to be replaced with? You're just replacing all `(` and `)` with `.`

Comment: Are you expecting the regexp replacement to automatically add extra indentation when it's matching a letter rather than number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually removing any `(` and `)` with a dot and a char with octal code `\001`.

If you want to replace `(...)` at the start of a line with one letter or digit inside use

```
result = re.sub(r'^\(([\da-z])\)', r'\1. ', text, flags=re.M)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AjWZDC/3). Note the use of `^` that enables matching at the start of a line only (it works together with `flags=re.M` flag).

To remove when there are 1+ digits *or* letters use

```
result = re.sub(r'^\((\d+|[a-z]+)\)', r'\1. ', text, flags=re.M)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AjWZDC/2). Here,

- `^` - matches start of a line
- `\(` - `(` char
- `(\d+|[a-z]+)` - 1 or more digits or 1 or more letters
- `\)` -  a `)` char.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = re.sub(r'\(([0-9a-z])\)', r'\1. ', text)
```

Comment: It will replace all occurrences of, say, `(1992)` in the text

Comment: There's only supposed to be one letter inside the parentheses.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it shouldn't?

Comment: @Barmar, deleted `+`

Comment: Now, you will remove them anywhere inside a string, while they must be matched only at the start of a line

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, maybe you can point me where you found requirement that it should replace occurences only at the start of line?